# Correctness of algorithm and its complexity

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, upper-bound

I am trying to solve problem of generation of so called activity-on-edge (activity-on-arc) network graph given based on given activity-on-node network graph.

So, I found [this](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1203/1203.3203.pdf) paper proposing an algorithm solving the problem, but I don't really understand the example given on pages 5-6, namely the partition of the graph into complete bipartite subgraph presented on page 6. Also I don't see difference between figures 11b and 11c - it looks that they must differ.

Could anyone explain how authors came to the solution and is it correct?

Paper citation: *Mouhoub, Nasser & Benhocine, Abdelhamid. (2012). An efficient algorithm for generating AoA networks. International Journal of Computer Science Issues. 9.*

Direct link to pdf: [link](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1203/1203.3203.pdf).

Comment: Can you edit the question to give a full citation to the paper (title, authors, where published), so others with a similar question can find this page via search?  Also usually it is best to ask only one question per post.

Comment: I'm rather suspicious about this paper.  The concepts and the algorithm are not explained clearly at all.  It really needs to be formalized appropriately - I couldn't understand it either.